# Does an Alcatel Genesys simulator/emulator exist?

Tags: telephony, pbx

Me and my team were tasked to integrate our application with Alcatel Genesys call center, but we don't have access to a proper instalation nor equipment (like, for instance, phones).

Is there some kind of software I can use to simulate such environment to test our application? And where should I begin researching how to do this integration?

(PS: I posted this same question on https://serverfault.com/questions/308381 - I didn't exactly know which of the sites this really belongs to).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like there is a public one.  You would probably have to go through one of their product managers.

The Genesys Platform SDK documentation appears to be public though:
http://docs.genesyslab.com/Documentation/PSDK

Answer (score 0):

The good news - you do not need phones to test integration with Genesys. The bad news is that integrating requires quite a lot of components and is quite complicated so there is no simulator or mock interface you could use. One of the best ways would be to get in contact with Genesys tech support who are usually quite helpful or pre-sales and ask them about access to a virtual demo image you could use for integration.

Also a great resource of information is their newly designed doc site:
http://docs.genesys.com/Documentation/OS

Also Alcatel has sold Genesys a while ago and they're independent now, just in case ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is. Genesys Simulator Toolkit. It will enable to emulate an Avaya PBX or a Simple TDM scenario. Last version also includes as Genesys SIP Server emultaor.
You won't care too much about the PBX on the other side for basic integrations, your goal is to learn the SDK and the TEvents (TLib). You can achieve this with the Emulator. You need to ask it to a Genesys representative.